# Genetic algorithm with Encog library takes hours to train and is not accurate?

Tags: java, eclipse, ocr, encog

I'm using Encog 2.4.0 with Java in my research to evaluate back-propagation and genetic algorithm in font digits (0-9) recognition. I'm using JavaCV to process my digits (images) to a text file of 0 and 1, with each line represent one font image image. Each font (line) has 256 attributes (0 or 1).
My network input node number is 256 and output node is 10 (classes) and I'm using sigmoid activation function in my network. My output also normalized to 0 and 1 (e.g. 1000000000 means 0, 0100000000 means 1 and so on till 9).
With 11 test run with different training set (100 to 700 samples) and test set (50 to 300) with different parameters for learning rate and momentum, I'm very happy with back-propagation performance with both accuracy and speed ( 10 seconds to < 4 minutes). But unfortunately :( with 11 tests with genetic algorithm with different parameters, I'm not able to get either accuracy or speed right. What takes for BP, 4 minutes for GA takes 2 - 13 hours and accuracy is also below 0.01 percent in most of the case and it seems it is by chance. I have tried initial population size from 200 to 500, mating population from 0.25 (25%) to 0.50 (50%) and mutation rate I have tried 0.1, 0.05, 0.01 and 0.001. I'm using FanInRandomizer.

The network input and output structure is similar to XOR example. In XOR input is an array of 4 X 2 and output is 4 X 1.

Mine is: 'No of samples' X 256 for input and 'No of samples' X 10 for output.

Can anybody please shed some light on where I'm going wrong ?

Thanks,
Hoss

Answer (score 1):

First, that is a really old version of Encog.  The genetic algorithm code has changed considerably in 3.x, that alone might help.

As to why it is failing to converge, that can be a difficult question, without looking at the actual data and experimenting.  A few ideas.

- I would make sure the population is being created properly. Take the best member of the population, and see if you can backprop train it to converge.  Make sure the activation functions are what you expect.
- Look at the weight ranges for the GA vs BP trained network and see if anything crazy is happening to push the GA weights to unusual ranges.